# HMS Toolkit Build error - not finding dependency in repositories

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to port an app for AppGallery. While trying to build over HMS it is giving me the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
```

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.huawei.hms:ads-identifier:3.4.40.300.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/huawei/hms/ads-identifier/3.4.40.300/ads-identifier-3.4.40.300.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/huawei/hms/ads-identifier/3.4.40.300/ads-identifier-3.4.40.300.pom
> - https://maven.google.com/com/huawei/hms/ads-identifier/3.4.40.300/ads-identifier-3.4.40.300.pom
> - https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/huawei/hms/ads-identifier/3.4.40.300/ads-identifier-3.4.40.300.pom
> Required by:

The repository is indeed in the gradle file. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, it seems that the HMS converter, although the latest version is adding some old dependencies:

[Could not find com.huawei.hms:hwid:5.3.0.301 & push kit when adding HMS alongside GMS using HMS Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921399/could-not-find-com-huawei-hmshwid5-3-0-301-push-kit-when-adding-hms-alongsid)

after updating to a newer version the errors were resolved.